# R: How to get confidence interval without this warning message?

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, confidence-interval, interpretation

The model is:

```
model <- glm(DW ~ P + DV_1, family = "binomial")
```

The variables are:

```
DW <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
P <- c(18.584898, 8.177430, -7.392020, -13.123626, 11.742363, 35.836419, 8.177430, 8.177430, 7.209096, 10.398933, -23.382043, -8.177430, 7.392020, 17.607980, -37.631207, -8.177430, 12.202439, -29.602930, -8.177430, 14.709837, 8.194932, 8.177430, -5.222738, 1.185302, 12.049662, 6.193046)
DV_1 <- c(45.49215, 55.40000, 51.63815, 36.12306, 34.78324, 41.17867, 59.14783, 62.45898, 55.04072, 53.76998, 52.31764, 44.71056, 42.23566, 50.08676, 61.34397, 49.59538, 38.21099, 51.05214, 44.69676, 40.83045, 46.09846, 53.45508, 54.73643, 50.26476, 48.75601, 53.68885)
```

If I try to obtain confidence interval, for each parameter, with `confint` I get these warning message:

> *glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred*

**For this specific model:**

1. Is it better to use `confint` or other functions?
2. How do I fix that warning?
3. Can I get reliable confidence interval, and how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the confidence interval for? Do you want one for each parameter in the model?

Comment: yes, I forgot to specify

Comment: [Here you go](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression). Have a read

Comment: @Sotos Thanks. I sincerely don't know what to do. Do you have any solution for this specific case?

Comment: Have a look at the third answer of that post which uses `arm` package. Very simple to follow

Comment: @Sotos That gives me another warning message: "Waiting for profiling to be done...Error in profile.glm(object, which = parm, alpha = (1 - level)/4, trace = trace) : profiling has found a better solution, so original fit had not converged". Anyway I like the approach, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can always calculate confidence intervals as this in `glm`, without having to rely on any type of commands:

`exp(confint.default(model))`

You can always use the bayesian approach recommended by Sotos. Depends on rely what you want to do. If this is like a HW question telling you to just do a glm model and confidence intervals then the above command will help you out.

Also if you run the `glm()`, with only one parameter and then use the `confint` command you will not get any warnings.

Comment: I noted that `confint.default` does not produce the warnings. What's the difference between `confint` and `confint.default` ?

Comment: The default method assumes asymptotic normality. Something that is usual from lm objects. I highly recommend using `?confint` and get all the goodies from the documentation.